# Rolling average with rollapply but getting non-NA value error

Tags: r

```
Browse[2]> head(ks)
                    [,1]                 
2014-02-14 14:27:00 "2014-02-14 14:27:00"
2014-02-14 14:32:00 "2014-02-14 14:32:00"
2014-02-14 14:37:00 "2014-02-14 14:37:00"
2014-02-14 14:42:00 "2014-02-14 14:42:00"
2014-02-14 14:47:00 "2014-02-14 14:47:00"
2014-02-14 14:52:00 "2014-02-14 14:52:00"
```

I am trying to find the rolling average of my dataframe (`ks`)

```
avg = rollapply(ks[,1], 2, mean, align='right', fill='extend')
```

but I am getting errors:

```
Error in approx(wix, unlist(object[wix]), xout = wrng) : 
  need at least two non-NA values to interpolate
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

Not really sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: You will need to show the output of `dput(head(ks))` so we know exactly what you have but this works for me: `x <- as.Date(c("2014-02-14 14:27:00",
"2014-02-14 14:32:00",
"2014-02-14 14:37:00",
"2014-02-14 14:42:00",
"2014-02-14 14:47:00",
"2014-02-14 14:52:00")); library(zoo); rollmeanr(x, 2, fill = NA)` or maybe what you want is `rollapplyr(x, 2, mean, partial = TRUE)`

Comment: P.S. It also works if we use `as.POSIXct` in place of `as.Date`.